# Reports and Dashboard view as pdf

Tags: reporting, pdf, dashboard

Is it possible for Salesforce to generate dashboard into pdf without having print, save as and so?

Right now, what I know is to use:

- conga composer.
- create vfp and use "renderAs=pdf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Salesforce doesn't offer functionality to generate print-ready PDFs directly from reports and dashboards. You'd need to build custom functionality to do this or use an AppExchange product, of which Conga Composer is one of several.